# My skin isn't loading

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My pals and I play on a "server" via Hamachi, because they don't want to buy MC (I have an account)

My skin appears correctly when I play singleplayer but the moment I connect to the "server" my skin becomes Alex, but one of my pals has a working skin active. 
How come mine isnt working?

Things I've tried:

- I checked the homepage, skin is loaded there, same goes for the launcher
- Restarted the game and waited about 3 minutes to let it load.

Comment: Your friend's server is set in offline mode so that he and others can play on the server with cracked launchers aka without buying the game. When offline mode is enabled the server doesn't communicate with Mojang servers and so skins don't get loaded in.

Comment: is there a way i can get my skin working?

Comment: You must use the same cracked client (not recommended) or install a Spigot server and use a plugin. Search skin restorer plugin spigot, and install it to your server.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Arqade does not support software piracy.

Answer (score 2):

In order to play with people that don't have an official copy of Minecraft you need to turn off the online mode in server.properties file. But you also break the connection between Microsoft servers and your server by doing that. So your server becomes unable to download skin files from Microsoft servers. In order to fix that you can install [spigot server](https://getbukkit.org/download/spigot) instead of a vanilla server and install a plugin called SkinsRestorer.